# How to report a Tor Browser crash

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, linux

Using the most recent Tor Browser Bundle (5.0a3) I experience crashes. I am running Linux, however since there is now a .desktop used it doesn't show me anything in the terminal. Even when I run the command without `--detach` I do not end up knowing what is going on, because there isn't any output.

Is there some way to report crashes? Wouldn't it make sense to have a crash reporter, similar to plain Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the .desktop file.

From wherever you've unpacked the Tor directory to, run `./tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser` with the `-v` (verbose) option. This will give you the terminal output you were used to seeing.

Answer (score 1):

The Tor Project maintains a [bug tracker](https://bugs.torproject.org/). Before you can open a new ticket. You need to register or log in. If you don't want to register, you can use the multi-user account with the account name cypherpunks and the password writecode. After you've logged in, choose [New Ticket](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/newticket) and try to describe as detailed as you can where you think the bug is. Have a look from time to time if someone commented on your report. Sometimes more information from you are needed.

The developers will have a look at your ticket an probably resolve it.

Comment: I meant it more like how can I provide valuable debug information? Is there any way to run Tor Browser in a mode that shows me what's actually going on?